Logical effect of gate on logical operators for the $[[4,2,2,]]$ code
The $S$ gate has the following effect (when applied to a Pauli operator $P$ by conjugation $SPS^{\dagger}$):
$$S: X \rightarrow Y $$
$$S: Z \rightarrow Z $$
The logical operators for the $[[4,2,2]]$ code can be defined as follows:
$$X_{L1}= XIXI$$
$$X_{L2}=XXII$$
$$Z_{L1}=ZZII$$
$$Z_{L2}=ZIZI$$
I have introduce $SSSS$ as a potential new logical gate for the $[[4,2,2]]$ code. I want to find its logical effect on the logical operators.
I know that $$SSSS: XIXI \rightarrow YIYI  $$ $$SSSS: XXII \rightarrow YYII$$ $$SSSS: ZZII \rightarrow ZZII$$ $$SSSS: ZIZI \rightarrow ZIZI$$
In other words, if we denote $SSSS$ as $S_{L}$, then:
$$S_{L}: X_{L1} \rightarrow - X_{L1}Z_{L2}  $$ $$S_{L}: X_{L2} \rightarrow - X_{L2}Z_{L1} $$ $$S_{L}: Z_{L1} \rightarrow Z_{L1} $$ $$S_{L}: Z_{L2} \rightarrow Z_{L2} $$
I have read on this post that $S_{L}$ implements a logical $CZ$ times a logical $ZZ$. However, I do not understand how this is the case.
Let me implement a logical $CZ$ followed by a logical $ZZ$ on the following, to check if the effect is the same:
$$X\otimes I \xrightarrow{CZ} X \otimes Z \xrightarrow{ZZ} ZX \otimes I$$
$$I \otimes X \xrightarrow{CZ} Z \otimes X \xrightarrow{ZZ} I \otimes ZX$$
$$Z \otimes I \xrightarrow{CZ} Z \otimes I \xrightarrow{ZZ} I \otimes Z$$
$$ I \otimes Z \xrightarrow{CZ} I \otimes Z \xrightarrow{ZZ} Z \otimes I$$
Which instead seems to have the effect:
$X_{L1} \rightarrow -X_{L1}Z_{L1}$
$X_{L2} \rightarrow -X_{L2}Z_{L2}$
$Z_{L1} \rightarrow Z_{L2} $
$Z_{L2} \rightarrow Z_{L1}$
Can anyone identify where I am going wrong?

When checking the effect of $CZ$ and $ZZ$ on the 4 Pauli strings, you have to use conjugation for each of the two transformations (as you do it for $S$).
You applied this correctly for the $CZ$ conjugations, for example: $CZ (X\otimes I) CZ = X \otimes Z$.
But your $ZZ$ conjugations are incorrect. It should be:
$$ (Z\otimes Z) (X \otimes Z) (Z \otimes Z) = - X\otimes Z$$
and likewise for the others. With correct application of $ZZ$ conjugation, the two results will agree.
